# How to show random data with highcharts with monthwise grouping

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have a requirement to show data on a chart and I am using Highcharts for the same , I have somewhat experience working with the same but kind of stuck for the following scenario to achieve:

I Have Month Wise Data For sales of products in units , which i wan to show on a column bar chart .

Data:

```
Month   Product     Units
Jan-17  Produc-1    23
        Product-2   45
        Product-3   23
        Product-4   34
        Product-5   67
        Product-6   87
        Product-7   12
        Product-10  34
Feb-17  Product-1   56
        product-4   23
        Product-11  45
        Product-13  54
        Product-8   12
        Product-22  23
        Product-20  87
        Product-2   98
17-Mar  Product-6   12
        product-43  34
        Product-23  58
        Product-12  73
        Product-9   89
        Product-1   36
```

How do i show the same on the chart with x-Axis as Jan-2017,Feb-2017 and Mar-2017 and Products as the column bar for respective months.

Thanks

Comment: Use multiple series to represent multiple products - you can example here http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/

Comment: Thanks , but that is the symmetric data , i need way to plot different products for different months ..

Comment: You can specify each point as a two dimensional array, the first value will be x/category which will be the month of the product. The concept of a series and its data is explained here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Comment: Thank you for pointing out , but i do not understand the point of 2D array , can you please help me with some fiddle ?

Comment: The fiddle with the data as 2d arrays is available in the link I pasted in my previous comment.